# Find the maximal number of parallel edges in a multi directed graph

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, max, networkx

Given a directed graph G that allows parallel edges, what is an efficient algorithm to find the maximal number of the parallel edges in G?

Comment: That would depend in part on how the directed graph is represented. There are multiple data structures that can handle a directed graph with parallel edges, and each has its own speed advantages and disadvantages. Which data structure are you assuming?

Comment: Sets of parallel edges are more commonly called matchings. This is a relatively easy problem if you're looking for an arbitrary maximal matching; harder if you're looking for the maximum maximal matching. Can you specify?

Comment: @Rory,  I would like to use an incident matrix A to represent the graph, in which A(i,j) = 1 if the vertex i and edge j are incident; and 0 otherwise.

Comment: That representation does not handle parallel edges (edges with the same staring and ending notes). With your "incident" statement it does not even handle *directed* graphs. It does handle them if you have A(i,j) storing the number of edges from node i to node j and if your application does not need to handle distinct edges that are parallel but only cares about the number of parallel edges. (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph#Undirected_multigraph_(edges_without_own_identity)).) Is that what you want?

Comment: I don't understand why incidence matrix cannot represent multigraphs. Please refer to the following example. http://www.math.uni.lodz.pl/~marmaj/GNT/Lectures/graph_representation.pdf

Comment: It can represent multigraphs but not directed (multi)graphs. You need to modify the definition such that an edge has distinct start and end vertices.

Comment: @RoryDaulton A(i,j) does *not* store the relationship between vertex i and vertex j (I misread it this way the first time around too).

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution is iterating over all pairs of nodes in the graph and counting the number of edges for each pair. However, many real life graphs are sparse - each node has only few neighbors relative to the total number of nodes in the graph. So a more reasonable solution would be to do the following:

```
import networkx as nx

# Build a sample graph:
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([('a', 'b'),('b', 'c'),('c', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'c'), ('a', 'b')])

max = 0
arg_max = ()
for source in G.nodes():
    for target in G.neighbors(source):
        n = G.number_of_edges(source, target)
        if n > max:
            max = n
            arg_max = (source, target)

print('max # of edges = {}, for nodes: {}'.format(max, arg_max))
```

Here, we only iterate over the neighbors of each node so even though we don't improve the runtime in worst case scenario (when the graph is a clique), we will probably improve it in practice for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Fitst, you need to modify your definition of incidence matrix, as what you have cannot represent direcred (multi)graphs. The change can be rather trivial, e.g. A(i,j) = 1/-1/0 if edge j enters/leaves/is unrelated to vertex i [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix).

Then your parallel edges are just identical columns in the incidence matrix. You can count them exactly like you would count duplicate elements in any old array, e.g. by sorting the array. Another method would be converting incidence matrix to  adjacency matrix and counting the number of duplicates that arise for each cell. Incidentally, this process looks a lot like bucket sort or radix sort of incidence matrix columns.